# File separator issues on windows/linux box

Tags: java, file, junit, io, nio

Below enum helps me avoid hard-coded directory values at different places in the JUNIT test cases. This seems to work in a development environment inside the IDE on a WINDOW's box.

As soon as I put this code on a LINUX box, the JUNIT classes cannot find the directories. The *Files.exists(sourcePath)* returns false. The same code had returned true on the IDE (windows). Any pointers on whats going wrong here?

```
public enum DIRECTORY {

    OUTPUT("resources/output"), RESOURCE("resources/resource"), PROCESSED_OUTPUT(
            "resources/output/resources/resource"), EXPLODED_WEBAPPS(
            "temp/webapps"), WEBAPPS("webapps");

    private String _name;

    private DIRECTORY(String _name) {

        this._name = _name;

    }

    public String getDirectoryName() {
        return _name;
    }

}
```

**Sample usage code of the enum**

```
private void restore_csv_files() {

        Path _processed_output = Paths.get(DIRECTORY.PROCESSED_OUTPUT
                .getDirectoryName());
        Path resource = Paths.get(DIRECTORY.RESOURCE.getDirectoryName());

        FileUtility.copy_files(_processed_output, resource);
        FileUtility.delete_files(_processed_output);
        FileUtility.delete_directory(_processed_output);

    }
```

**File Util class**

```
public static void copy_files(Path sourcePath, Path targetPath) {
        if (Files.exists(sourcePath) && Files.exists(targetPath)) {
            try {
                Files.walkFileTree(sourcePath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file,
                            final BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                        Files.copy(file,
                                targetPath.resolve(sourcePath.relativize(file)));
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Either Source or Target path does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Basically on the windows this thing work, but on the linux box, get a **sysout** "Either Source or Target path does not exist" (refer above code for sysout)

**Sample Exception**

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: webapps/web.war
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at com.temp.utils.FileUtility.alter_date_time_of_file(Unknown Source)
    at com.temp.webengine.WebEngineTest.test_web_app_updated_true(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
```

Comment: Resources are not files, and they exist in the CLASSPATH, not in the file system. Rethink.

Answer (score 5):

For File seperator, use [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

```
static String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Comment: I think `path.separator` will be also useful for enum `DIRECTORY`

Comment: You mean is that the reason it is failing. So you want me to use a path separator in the ENUM?

Comment: I don't think it is a path separator issue. If you have a look at the ENUM, the file separator is correctly used for linux (/). If at all it should have failed, it should have failed on WINDOWS box not linux. Hopefully the exception added should throw some light

Comment: you need to do some debugging, print the absolute path before if statement and check whether file actually exist.